# Proving $\cos\theta \sin\theta (\sin^2\theta -\cos^2\theta)=-\frac{\sin4\theta}{4}$

Tags: calculus, algebra-precalculus, trigonometry

Looking for some help with an explanation of the following simplification in trig,

$$\cos\theta \sin\theta (\sin^2\theta -\cos^2\theta)=-\frac{\sin4\theta}{4}$$

In simplifying this do they take the negative out of $(\sin^2\theta -\cos^2\theta)$ to get

$$-\cos\theta \sin\theta =-\frac{\sin4\theta}{4}$$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Heres a complete answer
$$\cos\theta \sin\theta (\sin^2\theta -\cos^2\theta)=\frac{\sin(2\theta)}{2}*-\cos(2\theta)$$

Again, 
$$\frac{-\sin(2\theta)\cos(2\theta)}{2}=\frac{-\sin(4\theta)}{4}$$

I mainly used these two relation $$\cos^2 (x)-\sin^2 (x)=\cos (2x)$$
which gives $$\sin^2 (x)-\cos^2 (x)=-\cos (2x)$$
and $$\sin(2\theta)=2\sin(\theta)\cos(\theta)$$
which gives 
$$\frac{\sin(2\theta)}{2}=\sin(\theta)\cos(\theta)$$
Similarly
$$\frac{\sin(4\theta)}{2}=\sin(2\theta)\cos(2\theta)$$

Comment: shouldn't it be divded by 4 in the end not 2?

Comment: Edited the answer

Comment: awesome explanation, thanks your your help

Comment: You're welcome :)

Answer (score 2):

No use $\cos^2 (x)-\sin^2 (x)=\cos (2x) $. Then use $\cos (a)sin (a)=2\sin (2a) $

Comment: so since $sin^2x-cos^2x$ it becomes $-cos(2x)$?

Comment: and where does the divide by 4 part come in?

Comment: See the edit now

Answer (score 0):

HINT

Hope short hand helps.. non-unity arguments written to the right

$$  s^2 -c^2 = -c2 $$

given

$$ \dfrac12 \, s2 \cdot -c2 =  - s4 /4 $$